The graphs of $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx+ c$ and $g(x) = x^2 +mx + n$ are shown. What is the area bounded by $y =\frac{g(x)}{f(x) + 3}$ and the $x$-axis?
The graphs of $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx+ c$ and $g(x) = x^2 +mx + n$ are shown. What is the area bounded by $y =\frac{g(x)}{f(x) + 3}$ and the $x$-axis?

This is a question on our exam today and I was unable to solve it. I hope to receive some hints.
Thank you!

What have you tried? What all can you conclude from the given graph? Also were there any bounds between which the area was asked for?

@sudeep5221 Hi, I was able to work out that the roots of $g(x)$ are the same as the roots of the derivative of $f(x),$ which allows me to conclude that $a =\frac{3m}{2}$ and $b = 3n,$ but I wasn't unable to meaningfully proceed from that.

@sudeep5221 Regarding the bounds, I believe they're the intersections between $y$ and the $x$-axis.

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be the roots of $g(x)$. Then $f(\alpha)=7/2$ and $f(\beta)=-77/22$ (or reverse it doesn't matter). Furthermore, as I think you have shown, we have $g(x)=\frac{1}{3}f'(x)$. So we can write
$$y(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{3}f'(x)}{f(x)+3}.$$
Assuming you want the bounds for the area to be between where $y(x)$ intersects the x-axis (i.e. where $y(x)=0$, equivalently $g(x)=0$), we can write this as an integral:
$$A=\int_\alpha^\beta\frac{\frac{1}{3}f'(x)}{f(x)+3}=\left[\frac{1}{3}\ln(f(x)+3)\right]_\alpha^\beta=\frac{1}{3}(\ln(f(\alpha)+3)-\ln(f(\beta)+3))=\frac{1}{3}(\ln(7/2+3)-\ln(-77/27+3))\approx1.26$$

Thank you very much!

we can observe that $f(x)$ is a 3 degree polynomial and $f'(x)$ has 2 real distinct roots from the graph.
$f'(x)=0$ when $g(x)=0$ so $$\frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}=a$$ where $a$ is some constant. By comparing coeff of $x^2$ in $f'(x)$ we can calculate $a=3$
so $y=\frac 13\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)+3}$
let $f'(x)=0$ at $x=a,b$ for $a\lt b$
from graph its obvious that $f(x)\gt{-3}$ for $x\in[a,b]$.
y cuts x-axis only at 2 points when $f'(x)=0$ ie at $x=a,b$ and $f(x)+3$ always greater than $0$ for $x\in(a,b)$
so the area between between y and x-axis will be bounded.
it can be calculated
$$|\int_a^b y.dx|\implies|\int_a^b\frac 13\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)+3}.dx|$$
$$\implies|[ln(f(x)+3]_a^b|\frac 13$$
in the graph it is given that $f(a)=\frac 72$ and $f(b)=\frac{-77}{27}$

Thank you very much!
